# RFID reader - How to check if a card is still on the reader + there is a beep every one second if a card is on it - c#

Tags: c#, rfid, reader

I wrote a little program to read the ID of a RFID Testing Card.
It's pretty simple, you put the Card on the Reader, the Reader recognizes the ID and writes it into a TextBox.

First of all there is a problem, that you hear a beep every one second if a Card is on the Reader.
Is there a Chance to read the ID one time and then just check it every maybe 5 or 10 seconds if the Card is still on it or not?
So that the Reader doesnt beep all the time, it's pretty annoying.
It's a ChaFon RFID Smart Reader.

And if the program recognizes, that there is no Card on it, it Displays f.E.:
"No Card on the Reader"
And if there is one on it it says:
"Card is on the Reader - check again in 5 Seconds"

This is the Code of my TextBox and the Buttons.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RFID_card_reader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime time;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tbRFID.Focus();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time = DateTime.Now;
            lbOutlay.Items.Add(tbRFID.Text + " : " + time.ToString());
            tbRFID.Clear();
            tbRFID.Focus();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbRFID.Clear();
            tbRFID.Focus();
        }

        private void btClearOutlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbOutlay.Items.Clear();
            tbRFID.Focus();
        }

        private void tbRFID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbRFID.MaxLength = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RFID_card_reader
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it acts as a keyboard-wedge? i.e it just sends keystrokes to your app?  If so then your code is not integrated with it at all and so cannot control it at all ... to do so you would need an API as either provided by the manufacturer or a general HID based one like http://liblogicalaccess.islog.com/

Comment: Basically yes it does. I know that it is not connected, but I dont know how to constantly read/check that I receive data from the Reader. If I could set a flag to true if the Card is on, it would be easy

Comment: The annoying Thing is just that it beeps every second, so you have to put it on and immediately take it off the Reader and thats not practical.